# Multiple Lint Files For Each Build Type

Tags: android, gradle, lint

How would one configure gradle to point to different lint files for different build types?

We want to translate strings at the end of a development cycle. So we need to ignore translation errors thrown by lint only on the debug version. When we make a release build lint should then throw the translations errors. The following build.gradle throws a DSL method not found.

```
  android {

    buildTypes {

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            lintOptions debug
        }

        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix '.beta'
            versionNameSuffix '- beta'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    lintOptions {

        debug {
            disable 'TypographyFractions'
        }

    }

}
```